# Solution for backing up Salesforce data

Tags: data-export, automation, backup

We currently do a data backup of SFDC data every week via the Data Export feature in Salesforce. This process is very time consuming as the result of the data backup is 30+ files that all need to be downloaded independently, all of which are very large. Does anyone know of a better way to back up data for customers with larger databases like ours?

Comment: did you look on appexchange? many tools there

Comment: I did. Just looking for recommendations from those that have experience with this.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution that I have found that takes not much time to build has been using [Informatica](https://www.informatica.com/cloud.html#fbid=uHkjkEUB0iQ) On demand cloud version .

This involves some additional cost though.

If you want to do something for free go with data loader command line .The command line data loader allows you to schedule the data archival process .

Also I have used [Talend](https://www.talend.com/) in past which has free version but this will be some work for sure .